# Binary search - arrays

Tags: arrays, search, binary-search

I'm quite new to world of algorithms and don't know everything so I have to ask something, lately I have encountered an intereseting problem. As my assignment I am working on a program that has to count all occurences of a number in an array i.e. array[6] = {1, 2 , 2, 2, 3 ,3 }; user asks about '2' and answer is 3. I'm doing this by two parallel binary searches, one is looking for lowest index that number occurs and the other one for the highest. In the end I just substract those two values. And here comes the question: is there any faster/more efficient way to do it using only array? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your array have the sorted value??

Comment: Yes, my array is sorted.

Comment: Your solution will work only if the array is sorted. Even then you'll need to add one to the difference of `highindex-lowIndex` in order to get the correct solution. If the array is not sorted, then you will need to traverse the entire array and simply count the occurances of number n.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the value and get the count.

You can keep a dictionary of value as key and counter which will be increased every time you see that value in the array.

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite getting your idea. Is it something like creating an array of structs with number and count?

Comment: yes, use a hashmap (I think that's what it is called in other languages than c#) or dictionary, this will be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If you have some control over the in-memory layout of the data, you might want to look at Judy arrays.

Or to put a simpler idea out there: a binary search always cuts the search space in half. An optimal cut point can be found with interpolation (the cut point should NOT be the place where the key is expected to be, but the point which minimizes the statistical expectation of the search space for the next step). This minimizes the number of steps but... not all steps have equal cost. Hierarchical memories allow executing a number of tests in the same time as a single test, if locality can be maintained. Since a binary search's first M steps only touch a maximum of 2**M unique elements, storing these together can yield a much better reduction of search space per-cacheline fetch (not per comparison), which is higher performance in the real world.

n-ary trees work on that basis, and then Judy arrays add a few less important optimizations.

Bottom line: even "Random Access Memory" (RAM) is faster when accessed sequentially than randomly. A search algorithm should use that fact to its advantage.

Comment: Interpolation sounds great but my data is randomized.

Comment: you can also use hashmap

Answer (score 0):

If the array's already sorted then your method is OK (i.e. O(log n)). I'm not sure that you can be faster asymptotically.

I don't think that you can parallelise a binary search (but it's been a long time since I did that sort of stuff). Anyway, O(log n)'s not too shabby.

If your array isn't already sorted then the overhead of sorting (O(nlog N)) is obviously bigger than a simple linear scan through the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is already sorted from the lowest value to the highest, your method doesn't seem to be unefficient. If it wasn't ordered, you would have to search through all the array from the beginning to the end and then the cost would be linear O(n)